# Do car rental companies in Europe accept a driver's license with a change of name document?

Tags: europe, car-rentals, paperwork

I am thinking about changing my name, but while it would be easy for me to get a passport replacement with the new name, doing a name change on the driver's license would be not so easy (because I travel a lot).

So I am wondering if I can rent a car (in Europe), presenting a passport with my new name, a driver's license with my old name, and a name change document.

Comment: Where is your drivers' license from, and are you a non-EU citizen?

Comment: @jpatokal I'm a U.S. citizen, and the driver's license was issued in the U.S.

Comment: Without knowing what state you reside in, it seems quicker to walk into the DMV to change your license than to send off for a new passport.

Comment: In my country, if you change your name you'd have to by law change the driver's license too :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out what car rental companies are available at your destination, then call/email them to ask. Try to ensure whoever you ask checks policy rather than just answering what they think is right - because you may find whoever is at the desk on the day you collect has a different idea, and it could be important to show them the correct answer.

I'd also be keen to check if the law of the countries you intened to drive in are happy with this arrangement. In some European countries you can be compelled to hand over your license when stopped by law enforcement and there is of course the possibility you get into an incident of some form. It could be problematic if it turns out that you were breaking the law with a driving license not in your legal name.